# How to execute query longer than 32767 characters on Firebird?

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm developing a Java web application that deals with large amounts of text (HTML code strings encoded using base64), which I need to save in my database. I'm using Firebird 2.0, and every time I try to insert a new record with strings longer than  32767 characters, I receive the following error: 
`GDS Exception. 335544726. Error reading data from the connection.`

I have done some research about it, and apparently this is the character limit for Firebird, both for query strings and records in the database. I have tried a couple of things, like splitting the string in the query and then concatenating the parts, but it didn't work. Does anyone know any workarounds for this issue?

Comment: Use a `PreparedStatement` And why are you doubling the size of the HTML by storing it base64 encoded?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name even with prepared statements, the length of strings is still 32 kilobytes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I understood the question in a way that the problem is the total length of the SQL statement which exceeds that limit due to string concatenation.

Comment: Which version of Jaybird are you using? As far as I know the "Error reading data from the connection" shouldn't occur in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebird query strings are limited to 64 kilobytes in Firebird 2.5 and earlier. The maximum length of a varchar field is 32766 byte (which means it can only store 8191 characters when using UTF-8!). The maximum size of a row (with blobs counting for 8 bytes) is 64 kilobytes as well.

If you want to store values longer than 32 kilobytes, you need to use a BLOB SUB_TYPE TEXT, and you need to use a prepared statement to set the value.

Comment: Why only 8191 chars in UTF-8? This is only true if you'll store only characters from the Unicode Supplementary Planes, i.e. chars with code point > U+FFFF, which is very unlikely. The most used characters will still use only 1 byte, or 2 bytes for languages that don't use latin script.

Comment: @Bozzy It is only 8191 characters, because the implementation uses the negative assumption of 4 bytes per character even if most characters will only take 1 or 2 bytes. This results in a clear and well-defined upper limit of characters. A secondary reason is that some sizes are communicated in bytes, while other parts of Firebird and its clients need to be able to derive maximum number of characters. Using the max bytes per character was the design choice to solve that.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Actually it makes sense. Thank you for the info.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to save large amount of text data in the database - just use BLOB fields. Varchar field size is limited to 32Kb.
For better performance you can use binary BLOBs and save there zipped data.